# Calling a method from another script throwing cannot find module

Tags: node.js

I have written this method here

In redisController.js

```
export default getAllKeysWithValue =  async (req,res) => {

    client.keys('*',  (err, keys)=> {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        for(let i =0;i<keys.length;i++){
            client.get(keys[i],function(err,data){
            
                console.log(`key is ${keys[i]} and value is ${data}`);

                res.send("LOOK AT YOUR LOG :)")
            })
        }
        

      });   
 
    
}
```

And in the routes.js

```
import express from 'express'
import getAllKeysWithValue from "../controllers/redisController"
import getRedisValue from "../controllers/redisController";
import postRedisValue from "../controllers/redisController";





var router = express.Router();



router.get("/getAll",getAllKeysWithValue)
router.get('/getKey/:keyRedis',getRedisValue);
router.post('/createKeyValue',postRedisValue);



export default  router;
```

And in the server.js

```
import express from 'express'

import bodyParser from 'body-parser';



import redisRoute from './routes/routes';


const app = express();

const PORT = 3001;


bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false})
app.use(express.json())
 

app.use("/redisLogic",redisRoute);




app.listen(PORT,() =>{
    console.log("SERVER r");
})
```

But iam getting  **Cannot find module 'C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\firstTask\routes\routes' imported from C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\firstTask\server.js
Did you mean to import ../routes/routes.js?**

[!Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L5km.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L5km.jpg)

Comment: Can you show file structure of your project?

Comment: Yes the file exists,  i ll update the project structure now.

Comment: Just updated it

Answer (score 0):

It can be so simple as a piece of cake.
You're using the `CommonJS` in your back-end side.
Try using `ES6` method.
**Syntax :**

```
const . . .  = require('./')
```

**Hint:** If you want to have multiple defaults in **JavaScript**, you can do it through this syntax:

`export default { Function1, Function2 }`

**Hint:**
In **`NodeJS`**, It's better to use **`module.exports`** and **`exports.Function` = ..**

However, There's a difference between them that you can surf the Internet to check it out.

Comment: I want to use import not require

Comment: Both of them are used the same. however there's a tiny difference.In TypeScript, we apply import to utilize our controllers or models.Whereas in NodeJS, we use module.exports or exports to get round the issue. take a look at my code here. It'll hammer all the things home much more easier.   https://github.com/Erfan-Motallebi/nodejs-mysql-CRUD-async

Answer (score 0):

A default import can be imported in another file as `import myDefaultImport from './myFile.js'`

You cannot have multiple default exports in one file. So in `redisController.js` export your functions as

```js
// declare function
export function getAllKeysWithValue() { ... }
export function postRedisValue () { ... }

// the one allowed default export per file
export default myFunction() { ... }
```

In other file you import them as

```js
import myFunction, { getAllKeysWithValue, postRedisValue } from `path-to-controller`
```

These are ES6 in/exports and straightforward.

The path and usage of your redisRouter is correct. I guess the error happens cause you have mutliple default exports.